# Problems writing to excel after sorting dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I had the below and everything was working fine:

```
finalDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(compareDictList)

def highlight_rows(row):
    if row["Inconsistencies"] == "Y":
        return['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)

formatted = finalDF.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis = 1)

formatted.to_excel("FinalReport.xlsx", index=False, columns=['XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ'])
```

But then wanted to first sort the df before writing to excel, so input the single step to sort the df and use that new sorted df with the format styler, but now I'm getting an error when I try to run it all together. The sort part works, but won't highlight and write to excel. Unfortunately I can't share the actual data, here's the code:

```
finalDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(compareDictList)

sortedDF = finalDF.sort_values(by=['XXXX', 'YYYY'])

def highlight_rows(row):
    if row["Inconsistencies"] == "Y":
        return['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)

formatted = sortedDF.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis = 1)

formatted.to_excel("FinalReport.xlsx", index=False, columns=['XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ'])
```

Comment: I understand you can't share the data but could you add a minimum version with dummy data so we can reproduce [see minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Could you also share the error you are getting?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue and I really have no idea what could be causing it.  The shape returned by the style.apply() is different on the sorted pandas but why remains a mystery to me. I would recommend to open an issue on the [Pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) directly as it may be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally understood the issue. The problem is when the first row does not meet the criteria, the `highlight_rows()` returns `None` which is not the right dimension. To solve this, just return something of the same shape when the condition is False:

```py
def highlight_rows(row):
    if row["Inconsistencies"] == "Y":
        return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)
    else:
        return ['background-color: None'] * len(row)
```